# What are the electronics components that have characteristics like Neon Lamp?

Tags: zener

Neon lamps have higher breakdown voltage than its operating voltage.
When brokendown, it acts like a zener at its operating voltage.

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Doutnavka.svg/330px-Doutnavka.svg.png]

Comment: The only one that springs to mind is a Neon lamp.

Comment: Gas lasers behave the same way, if I remember correctly, but well they are just improved neon lamps.

Comment: A thiristor is a typical current controlled negative resistance device (S shaped lambda diode)

Comment: http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/S-Type+Negative-Resistance+Semiconductor+Device , https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Negative_Resistance , https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Negative_Differential_Resistance . Gas ionization would have the current "S" characteristics, Arc welding, Lightning, Florescent lights, Spark gap, etc.  Gas discharge limits frequency response. Emulating "S" curve with a circuit can overcome that.

Answer (score 6):

How about a diac or sidac diode? They have somewhat similar curves but in different ranges.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIAC

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you might consider a unijunction transistor.

[image]